# Automatically return success for ReCAPTCHA 2 in php

Tags: php, recaptcha

I'm working on an application that has recaptcha built in for login and registration.  Ideally I would like the user to be able to turn off the feature, but there is a ton of logic going on in the login/register forms that makes it hard to wrap in an if statement the way I'd like to.  I can wrap most of it, but it gets really messy in some parts.  Ideally, I'd like recaptcha to THINK it got a success message for part of it. Specifically for this statement.

```
if ($response != null && $response->success) {
```

Is there any way to pass something like true into my $response variable to make it think it got a success message?